# Does AlphaImageLoader png hack work on IE6 with SSL?

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer-6, iepngfix

Does DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader work over SSL?  I've been trying to no avail to get this to work, but it does work fine over an insecure connection.

All of the PNG hacks I've found use this method, and search results haven't yielded anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

> **The Cause**
>
> Anytime you get the security error
>   about some content not being secure,
>   it is because something is being
>   linked to that is coming from a
>   non-HTTPS (insecure) connection.
>   Tracking it down led us to see that it
>   was some CSS tags that allow for PNG
>   transparency in IE6 and IE7, using the
>   CSS "filter" property and the
>   "AlphaImageLoader" plugin. Here's the
>   particular line of code:
>
> ```
> filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/facebox/tr.png', sizingMethod='scale');
> ```
>
> **The Solution**
>
> So the solution is to use a full
>   secure URL with "HTTPS://" to the png
>   image. IE sees that AlphaImageLoader
>   as a plugin. And all plugins in IE 6,7
>   are required to only reference cached
>   images. The images cached are not
>   HTTPS (or secure), and so the secure
>   content error popup is shown when the
>   AlphaImageLoader requests the images.
>   So the following request worked
>   correctly.
>
> ```
>  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader (src='https://www.livingroad.com/images/facebox/tr.png', sizingMethod='scale');
> ```
>
> Oh, and don't try to use spaces in
>   the URL for the AlphaImageLoader! This
>   is another known bug in the plugin.

From [AlphaImageLoader SSL support in IE6 and IE7](http://david-oliver-cooper.com/internet-programming/90-alphaimageloader-ssl-support-in-ie6-and-ie7.html)